# Setting static objects in java

Tags: java, string, static

I have a class `GlobalData`

```
public class GlobalData {
    public static  String SERVER_ROOT;
    public static  String LOGIN_JSP = GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT + "login.jsp";
    public static  String HOME_JSP = GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT + "s/home.jsp";
    public static  String Logout = GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT + "Logout";
    public static ServletContext SERVLET_CONTEXT;
 }
```

i set these strings from contextListener

```
        GlobalData.SERVLET_CONTEXT = contextEvent.getServletContext();
        GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT = GlobalData.SERVLET_CONTEXT.getContextPath()+"/";

        System.out.println("setting server root : " + GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT);
        System.out.println("setting Home jsp : " + GlobalData.HOME_JSP);
        System.out.println("setting Login : " + GlobalData.LOGIN_JSP);
        System.out.println("setting Logout : " + GlobalData.Logout)
```

**Output Is :**

```
setting server root : /JCMM/
setting Home jsp : nulls/home.jsp
setting Login : nulllogin.jsp
setting Logout : nullLogout
```

I can't understand this behaviors. Can anyone find, where is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `GlobalData` class is intialized, all the static variables are set.  There is no value for `SERVER_ROOT`, so it gets initialized to `null`.  Then the next 3 variables are initialized.  When using `+` to concatenate strings, a `null` results in the *String* "null", so each of the 3 values `LOGIN_JSP`, `HOME_JSP`, and `Logout` start with "null".

Later, you set SERVER_ROOT, but you don't update the other 3, so they remain as strings with "null" at the front.

Comment: Great Explaination !!  Thanks !!